# Foreground service gets stopped when we clear applications using task manager (All clear options)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-service

When we clear all from task manager application like YouTube, media player not get cleared from task manager. Is there any way to avoid app getting cleared from the task manager or Location service may not get killed.

LocationService.kt

```
class LocationService : Service() {
    private lateinit var mFusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private lateinit var mLocationRequest: LocationRequest
    private lateinit var mLocationCallback: LocationCallback

    override fun onCreate() {
        startForeground(RideManager.RIDE_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                RideManager.getRideNotification())
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        createLocationRequest()
        createLocationCallback()
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    private fun createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest()
        mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        mLocationRequest.interval = Constants.UPDATE_INTERVAL
        mLocationRequest.fastestInterval = Constants.FASTEST_INTERVAL
    }

    private fun createLocationCallback() {
        mLocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult)
                val currentLocation = locationResult!!.lastLocation
                if (currentLocation != null) {
                    if (RideManager.mIsTripStarted)
                        LocationMocUp.getInstance().onLocationUpdate(currentLocation)
                    else
                        mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback)
                }
            }
        }
        getLocation()
    }

    private fun getLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return
        }
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper())
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        if (!::mFusedLocationClient.isInitialized || !::mLocationCallback.isInitialized) {
            super.onDestroy()
            return
        }
        mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback)
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
        startForeground(RideManager.RIDE_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                RideManager.getRideNotification())
    }
}
```

Above code fetching location inside foreground service.

Comment: Not sure .. but try to return `START_NOT_STICKY` or `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` in `onStartCommand`

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: @Zain I already tried with START_REDELIVER_INTENT, but it not worked

Comment: @AtickFaisal Issue is same for all versions.